# jquery - attr data only running on first div class

Tags: jquery

Basicly i made a function settimeout as attr, now the problem I'm having that it always show the first class of data-time

With the below code, data-time only call of first class

```
<div id="frame1">
    <div class="logo" data-time="0"></div>
    <div class="heading" data-time="600"></div>
    <div class="subheading" data-time="900"></div>
</div>
<div id="frame2">
    <div class="logo" data-time="1200"></div>
    <div class="heading" data-time="900"></div>
    <div class="subheading" data-time="600"></div>
</div>

// JS Code
var a = $('.logo');
var b = $('.heading');
var c = $('.subheading');
var val = $([a,b,c]);

animationstart();

function animationstart() {
    val.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var time = $(this).attr('data-time');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.addClass('animated');
        }, time);
        console.log(time);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in `div` element selectors. `$('.logo')`, `$('.heading')`, `$('.subheading')`  will return array of elements, so you should apply all you want to each found element.

```js
var a = $('.logo');
var b = $('.heading');
var c = $('.subheading');
var val = $([a,b,c]);

animationstart();

function animationstart() {
    val.each(function(index, foundElements) {
        foundElements.each(function(element) {
         var $this = $(this);
         var time = $(this).attr('data-time');
         setTimeout(function() {
            $this.addClass('animated');
         }, time);
         console.log(time);
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame1">
    <div class="logo" data-time="0"></div>
    <div class="heading" data-time="600"></div>
    <div class="subheading" data-time="900"></div>
</div>
<div id="frame2">
    <div class="logo" data-time="1200"></div>
    <div class="heading" data-time="900"></div>
    <div class="subheading" data-time="600"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

refer below code-

```js
//jquery
var a = $('.logo');
var b = $('.heading');
var c = $('.subheading');
var val = $([a,b,c]);

 animationstart();
function animationstart() {
val.each(function(ind, el) {
      el.each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
var time = $(this).attr('data-time');
  (function(t){
    setTimeout(function() {
   $this.addClass('animated');
}, t);
console.log(t);
  //
  })(time);
   })
 

})}
```

```html
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame1">
<div class="logo" data-time="0"></div>
<div class="heading" data-time="600"></div>
<div class="subheading" data-time="900"></div>
</div>
<div id="frame2">
<div class="logo" data-time="1200"></div>
<div class="heading" data-time="900"></div>
<div class="subheading" data-time="600"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is closure used here?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = $('.logo');
var b = $('.heading');
var c = $('.subheading');
var val = $([a,b,c]);

animationstart();
function animationstart() {
val.each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.each(function(){
var time = $(this).attr('data-time');
setTimeout(function() {
$this.addClass('animated');
}, time);
console.log(time);
});
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame1">
<div class="logo" data-time="0"></div>
<div class="heading" data-time="600"></div>
<div class="subheading" data-time="900"></div>
</div>
<div id="frame2">
<div class="logo" data-time="1200"></div>
<div class="heading" data-time="900"></div>
<div class="subheading" data-time="600"></div>
</div>
```

You are looping only array. You have to loop through all the element to achieve your requirement.
https://jsfiddle.net/9ah90pzu/2/

Comment: Avoid providing link only answers.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Thanks!.  Please advice me how to add this code snippet.

Comment: [https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)   Check this out.